# How can I apply a ratio distribution for modelling quantities per hour?

Tags: ratio

I'm faced with an interesting situation regarding modelling rates of two populations. Say that I collected the following quantity from each of my employees:

```
Wood Chopped / Per Person / Per Hour
```

I give them a treatment of working faster. It seems straightforward to measure the quantity above and apply a statistical test (Student's t or what not). However, I just ran into this concept of "Ratio Distributions" on Wikipedia. I have read the article to the best of my ability, but I'm unsure how I could effectively apply ratio distributions to this toy setup. Could someone guide me on how I could effectively use a ratio distribution in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ratio distributions as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution  for your toy example.   Ratio distributions apply for the case where both numerator and denominator are random variables.

In your example the denominator is a known constant, so no randomness.